# Uploading a 60MB XML file to an Umbraco Node causes endless looping

Tags: xml, file-upload, umbraco

I have a file upload field on an Umbraco content node, where a user of the sites back-end is able to upload a 60MB XML file, which is then processed by the server. The processing part works fine.

The issue is that it uploads about 30% of the file (according to the status bar in Chrome), but then starts to upload from 0% again. It continues to do this at least four times in a loop.

My first thought was that the server was timing out, but my settings in web.config should allow for an hour, and up to 2GB.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,>,:" />
</system.web>
```

Is there something else that I'm missing here? Or is there something strange about how Umbraco wants to handle a large XML file?

**Edit:** Managed to upload the file without any problems in IE7 (I know, right?), but I'm still getting the problem with Chrome of it going up to 30% and then returning back to 0%.

Answer (score 6):

If you run IIS7+ you also need to specify maxAllowedContentLength (default is 30000000 bytes):

```
<system.webServer>        
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="60000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but that section was already in the web.config, and was set suitably high. It seems to now be more of a cross-browser issue.